# google places api help c#

Tags: c#, api

I dont have much experience with google apis at all , however I need to implement it and would appreciate if you could help me

I have to implement google places api(?) to get results form google places and all details associated with that place

For example if you type [pizza London](http://www.google.co.uk/#q=pizza+london&hl=en&prmd=ivnscm&source=lnms&tbm=plcs&ei=xM4MTuG_BoX1sgbbo_TuDg&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=6&ved=0CD0Q_AUoBQ&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=8f5d0716bdf89e36&biw=1280&bih=923) in google places search you'll get 10 places per page. What I need is get "[link to that site](http://maps.google.co.uk/maps/place?hl=en&prmd=ivnscm&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&biw=1280&bih=923&um=1&ie=UTF-8&q=pizza%20london&fb=1&gl=uk&hq=pizza&hnear=0x47d8a00baf21de75:0x52963a5addd52a99,Westminster,%20London&cid=9114137073634419220&ei=yc4MTviKHcOe-wbw1aHdDQ&sa=X&oi=local_result&ct=placepage-link&resnum=1&ved=0CCgQ4gkwAA)" and xml(preferable) type of result with details about that place, such as address, contact, link to website, and payment options.

I dont know if something like this is even possible but if it is I would appreciate if you post an example of how it works

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sry but what could I have tried except googling? I'm not looking for c# code if that's what you understood, but for example of api call (api function)

Answer (score 4):

Basically you will need to register and get a key to use google places. Once you have the key you can access it like this ...

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=31.1556451,-93.7761955&radius=7500&sensor=false&key=enter-google-key-here&types=bar
```

which lists all bars within 7.5km of the place with latitude: 31.1556451 and longitude: -93.7761955

--- Additions in response to comment below ---

If you only have a place (like London) and not a latitude and longitude to go with it, you can try a two step process -- use google geocoding api to get the lat lon and then use that to search for pizza using the google places api.

Comment: yep, I sow that on their page, but that doesn't solve the problem at least I dont think so. Could you modify that link so it shows results for pizza london

Comment: @Anthony, sorry for misunderstanding your question. I have updated my answer -- hope it helps.